# pandas datetime Cannot convert input [[datetime.datetime(2007, 10, 30, 0, 0)]] of type <class 'numpy.ndarray'> to Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

[python](/questions/tagged/python) [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) [datetime](/questions/tagged/datetime) problem.

```
res = pd.DataFrame(res)
```

```
res = res.reindex(pd.date_range(res.index[0], res.index[-1])).fillna(0)
```

the error is :

> Cannot convert input [[datetime.datetime(2007, 10, 30, 0, 0)]] of type <class 'numpy.ndarray'> to Timestamp.

the dateframe `res` is show in the picture
[image]

How to solve this bug?

Hope solve this bug,and Fill empty date rows with zeros

Comment: and my goal is to caculate AR of a stock, like this `res.mean() * 365`

Comment: your index elements are array type so you have to reach inside the array. try use res.reindex(pd.date_range(res.index[0][0], res.index[-1][0]))

Comment: I do llike you say,but  a new bug `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

Comment: you should probably start by converting your index to a pandas DatetimeIndex. you're more likely to get a helpful solution if you can provide example data as text instead of an image.